# Methods displayed as strikethrough text

Tags: java, selenium

Can anyone tell me why the methods `pageloadtimeout` and `implicitlywait` are displayed as strikethrough text in my `testbase` class?

[image: strikethrough methods]

Comment: Selenium version?

Comment: The strikeout is done by your ide, it gets applied to all deprecated methods for any supported programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

The methods `WebDriver.Timeouts pageLoadTimeout​(long time, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit)`is deprecated.

Use `pageLoadTimeout(Duration)` that sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error, instead.

See: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html

Answer (score 0):

The Method you have used is outdated.
Use Below method will help you.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```